# Generating a table in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating tables dynamically in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226541/creating-tables-dynamically-in-jquery)

I have two Arrays, `letters = [A,B,C,...]` and `numbers = [1,2,3,...]`, and would like to generate a html table with `numbers` as the headers and `letters` as the first entry (and then I can fill it in with values which I have). *Is this possible for general Arrays?*

That is, as shown below:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th>1</th>
       <th>2</th>
       <th>3</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr id="A">
       <td>A</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="B">
       <td>B</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="C">
       <td>C</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>​
```

Comment: _"Is this possible for general Arrays?"_ - Of course. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DrColossos eeep, that "duplicate" looks horrific.

Comment: @hayden It's not about the code posted ;) but the ideas proposed in the answers... I would not use the code posted by the author any time, but the solutions are viable IMO.

Comment: @DrColossos This is much cleaner in both the question and the simplicity of the answers... Although the duplicate appears to share the same title, IMO the content is complete junk! Ah well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the first way that came to mind:

```
var letters = ["A","B","C"],
    numbers = [1,2,3],
    $table = $("<table/>"),
    $body = $("<tbody/>").appendTo($table),
    $row = $("<tr><th></th></tr>");

$.each(numbers,function(i,val){
  $("<th/>").text(val).appendTo($row);
});
$("<thead/>").append($row).appendTo($table);

$.each(letters, function(i,val) {
  $row = $("<tr/>").attr("id",val).appendTo($body);
  $("<td/>").text(val).appendTo($row);
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
    $row.append("<td/");
});

$table.appendTo("body");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ocomit/edit#javascript,html,live

Yes it could be prettier and/or more efficient. This uses only very rudimentary jQuery methods - if you're not sure about any of them you know [where to look](http://api.jquery.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one :

```
    var html = '';
    letters = [A,B,C];
    numbers = [1,2,3];
    html+= "<table><thead><tr><th></th>";
    for(i=0;i<letters.length;i++)
       html+="<th>"++letters[i]"</th>"; 
    html+= "</tr></thead>";
    html+= "<tbody>";
    for(j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
    {
       html+="<tr id='"+numbers[j]+"'>";
       html+="<td>"+numbers[j]+"</td>";
       for(k=1;k<letters.length;k++)
           html+= "<td></td>";
       html+= "</tr>";
    }    
    html+= "</tbody>";
    html+= "</table>";
```

And please alert "html" and you will get your desired output.

Comment: I would +1 for using a javascript-only solution except you read his question wrong. He wanted the numbers in the header and the letters in the table data.