# How to create a table inside a DIV tag using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have created a data table using

```
<script>
 var table = '<table border="0" id="tblTestCases">';

            table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length + "</td></tr>";
            $searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
                table+="<tr bgcolor='#ccccff'><td>Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if cursor is displayed/blinking after mouse click <br /> 2)Check if a text can be entered inside</td></tr>";
            });

            table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length + "</td></tr>";
            $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                table+="<tr bgcolor='#6666ff'><td>Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if the button is clickable or not <br /> 2) Check if the submission result is displayed after mouse click";
            });
</script>
```

I want to put the table inside a DIV tag. But the script is creating the table inside the body and not where I want it to be. Is there any way I can put the same table inside the DIV?

Thanks in advance.
PS. There are lot of entries inside the table. I added only 2 for demo purpose.

Comment: Where is the current code that adds it to the body? Code to add it to a div will be very similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating tables dynamically in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226541/creating-tables-dynamically-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
 var table = '<table border="0" id="tblTestCases">';

            table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length + "</td></tr>";
            $searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
                table+="<tr bgcolor='#ccccff'><td>Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if cursor is displayed/blinking after mouse click <br /> 2)Check if a text can be entered inside</td></tr>";
            });

            table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length + "</td></tr>";
            $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                table+="<tr bgcolor='#6666ff'><td>Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if the button is clickable or not <br /> 2) Check if the submission result is displayed after mouse click";
            });
</script>
```

And now you have this HTML just put it inside a `div`, for ex. this is the HTML:

```
<div id="testing"></div>
```

Now do:

```
$("#testing").html(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use folowing code snippet as container in html:

`<div id="container"></div>`

and update script like

```
<script>
var table = '<table border="0" id="tblTestCases">';

        table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length + "</td></tr>";
        $searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
            table+="<tr bgcolor='#ccccff'><td>Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if cursor is displayed/blinking after mouse click <br /> 2)Check if a text can be entered inside</td></tr>";
        });

        table+="<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td colspan='3'>Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length + "</td></tr>";
        $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
            table+="<tr bgcolor='#6666ff'><td>Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td><td> Test cases : <br /> 1) Check if the button is clickable or not <br /> 2) Check if the submission result is displayed after mouse click";
        });
$("#container").html(table);
</script>
```